# jQuery AJAX auto refresh values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a table that contains rows like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class='tempo' id='<?php print $id;?>'></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Also I have this jQuery function:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(

function ()
{
   $('.tempo').load('orari_pause/tempo_online.php?id=' + $(this).attr('id'));
}, 1000);
```

The **Ajax** call fails, the `$_REQUEST` method for id element one **tempo_online.php** page returns **"undefined"**.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: How about if you go to "orari_pause/tempo_online.php?id=1" (1 is an example) by browser?

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` is undefined

Comment: `$(this).attr('id'))` instaed of this try `$('.tempo').attr('id'));`

Comment: change it to `$('.tempo').attr('id')`

Comment: your `this` inside of timeout callback is not a `div` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `$(this).attr('id')` is undefined.

If you have multiple rows and you want to update each row with the correct value, you need to loop over the rows.

Something like this:

```
$('.tempo').each(function(index) {
    // Here $(this) refers to 1 specific row / element
    $(this).load('orari_pause/tempo_online.php?id=' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

But note that using an interval (as opposed to a timeout you set when the previous one is done...), will lead to a lot of simultaneous and probably overlapping ajax requests on the same elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the attribute to `data-id`:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class='tempo' data-id='<?php print $id;?>'></div>
  </td>
</tr>

$('.tempo').each(function(index,v) {
    $(v).load('orari_pause/tempo_online.php?id=' + $(v).attr('data-id'));
});
```